# Ajax auto suggest does not show letters in sequential order.

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays

I am making a small script with javascript to find/display text from an array as I am typing. Sort of like, Google auto suggest tool.

*Here is Js script:*

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode( $foo ); ?>;
     $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
});
</script>
```

*and the arrays in PHP*

```
  <?php 
        $foo = array("ambiguious","brown",
        "corps","demanding job","eat the pomes","fooling with it");
    ?>
```

Notice how each words in the array have different first letters than the rest ie.? 
 good, now when I type **a** instead of showing words that being with a (in this case "ambiguious"), it shows me all words which has a in them.

[image]

I thought about making `strpos()` to search through similar words, but it does not work. 
Any thoughts would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: At least the first three results [here](http://bit.ly/14gR3S7) will solve your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the API:

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

**Example: Using a custom source callback to match only the beginning of terms**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">

<script>
var tags = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer my **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/KVEmV/2/)**

### HTML:

```
List: <input id="myContent" />
```

### JQuery:

```
var myTags = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"];
$( "#myContent" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var matches = $.map(myTags, function(tag) {
            if (tag.toUpperCase().indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) === 0) {
                return tag;
            }
        });
        response(matches);
    }
});
```